# Unterschied zwischen "künftig" und "in der Zukunft"

Tags: word-usage, difference, synonym, idiomaticity

Sicher können diese beide Ausdrücke als Synonyme verwendet werden. Ich überlege aber, ob es eine bestimmte unterschiedliche Nuance zwischen beiden gibt.

> (1) Man sagt, dass in der Zukunft das Trinkwasser teuer sein wird.
>
> (2) Man sagt, dass das Trinkwasser künftig teuer sein wird.

Ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen zwei Sätzen nur einer des Stils?

Comment: Der Satzbau kann auch beibehalten werden, also "Man sagt, dass künftig das Trinkwasser teuer sein wird", bzw. umgekehrt. Man sollte nicht zwei Unterschiede machen, wenn man nur nach einem fragt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Als dritte Version käme noch

> Man sagt, dass in Zukunft das Trinkwasser teuer sein wird

in Frage (ohne das **der**).

*Künftig* und *in Zukunft* sind für mich praktisch gleichbedeutend und beziehen sich auf die sehr nahe Zukunft (ab sofort/ab nächster Woche/ab nächstem Jahr). Hier liegt der Unterschied wirklich nur im Stil.
*In **der** Zukunft* hingegen würde ich eher als etwas langfristiger ansehen (im Sinne von *ab mitte dieses Jahrhunderts müssen wir uns darauf einstellen, dass...*).

Comment: Kann es sein, dass Deine Unterscheidung zw. naher und ferner Zukunft rein auf Beispielsätze zurückgeht, die Dir spontan eingefallen sind? "Eher etwas langfristiger" klingt schon mal sehr vage. Auch kann diese Zukunft nicht nur unterschiedlich schnell beginnen, sie kann dann auch unterschiedlich lange anhalten. Was kurz- und langfristig ist hängt doch immer sehr vom Kontext ab. "Ich werde künftig nicht mehr so schmettern" beim Tischtennis oder "Künftig wird die Zahl der schwarzen Löcher im Universum" ...

Answer (score 2):

Ja, der Unterschied liegt lediglich im Stil. Je nach Satzbau kann das eine oder andere passender sein. (Zu)künftig ist lediglich das Adverb zu *in der Zukunft*.

Answer (score 0):

Beide Varianten sind im gegebenen Kontext gleichwertig, soweit völlig bedeutungslos, da der zeitliche Aspekt vorrangig durch die Beugung des Verbs allein ausgedrückt wird, sowie der Zeitpunkt weitgehend indefinit bleibt, da kein bestimmter Zeitpunkt genannt wird. Die analytische Ausdrucksweise ohne Beugung, die umgangssprachlich verwendet wird "morgen geh' ich" findet sich hier jedenfalls nicht. Allerdings ist *werden*, eine suplementäre Form des starken Verbs *sein*, eigentlich eine eigene Präsenzform. Insofern wird hier vielleicht eine archaische Ausdrucksweise deutlich, die *werden* überhaupt erst zum Hilfsverb gemacht hat. Zudem legt "in *der* Zukunft" eine definiertheit nahe, die kontextuell zu erschließen ist. So steht dazu im Kontrast die indefinite Form "in _ Zukunft".

Das Wort *künftig* zeigt lexikalische Nähe zu "Kunft", "Kunde", "Auskunft", daher würde ich es als *nach neuesten Erkenntnissen deuten*. Dies wäre widerum redundant, wenn der Satz mit *man sagt* eingeleitet wird. Soweit *kommen* hier wie auch in *Zukunft* zugrunde liegt, würde ich unterscheiden zwischen *kommend*, "in der kommenden Woche" bzw. *künftig* "potentiel, eventuel, erwartungsgemäß". Dabei ist *Kunde, kennen* aber abzugrenzen als von einer anderen Wurzel abgeleitet als *Zukunft, kommen*. Dagegen ist *zukünftig* zweifelsohne von *Zukunft* abzuleiten. Denkbar wäre, dass *zu* als eigenes Wort verstanden und etwa aus *zu künftigen Treffen* abgespalten hat. In der Tat ist bspw Alt-Griechisch *tha* ein altererbtes konjunktives Hilfsverb (vgl. W. Euler 2012, *Etymologie und Grammatik* p. 36 in Studia Etymologica Cracoviensia).

Es erscheint aus etymologischer Sicht insgesamt sinnvoller, das *zu-*Partikel beizubehalten.

---

<sub>Vergleichend bieten sich ohne bestimmte Reihenfolge und ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit oder Eindeutigkeit an: EN *to come*, *into [the future]*, NO *til*, DE *Ziel*, *Ankunft*, *ankündigen*, *zu*, *anzeigen*, Fränkisch *tarjet*, LA. *futurus*, PIE *bhuH, DE *bald*, PIE *bhel-, DE *Zufall*, LA *accident*, *cado* "fallen", GR *kata*, HET *katta* "ab, abwärts, herunter", DE *kennen, können*, LA *gnosis*, PIE *gneh3, LA *genesis* "Werdung, Entstehung, Geburt", PIE *genH, DE *beugen*, *vorbeugen*, PIE *bhew-, LA *profilax-*, DE *Zweifalt*, GR *haplo*, PIE *pleH "falten", LA *plus*, *pleo* "viel", PIE *pleH, EN *flow*, PIE ... GR *rheo* "fließen", DE *ausreichen*, *etwas zukommen lassen*, LA *inter*, DE *inzwischen*, *dazwischen*, *zuzweit*, *bei Zeiten*</sub>